# Inserting rails into HTML file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

When writing an HTML file, why use `<%= INSERT RAILS HERE %>` vs. `<% INSERT RAILS HERE %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= %>` will return value and display in your page. Assume that you have person.name = 'Dark'

```
 <%= person.name %>
```

will display `Dark` in your web page.

`<% %>` will not return any value to your page. It just embed simple ruby code. Usually used with `control statement'.

```
 <% if person.present? %>
   <span><%= person.name %></span>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<%= %>` emits a string, `<% %>` runs code.

On the pedantic side, you're writing an ERb template, not an HTML file--the syntax is the same whether it's a template for HTML, JS, or whatever.

The [ERB docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) provide additional <sub>(but not complete)</sub> information.

Answer (score 0):

When we use `<%= %>` it simply displays the value returned, on the html page.
`<% %>` executed the code but doesn't dispaly it on the html page.